# I am curious as to how python is connected to websites

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, web, backend

I am a new programmer and I saw that Google is written in python. I know that HTML, CSS, and JS are used to make websites, so how is python "linked" to this. This is probably a very basic question but I am new to all this.

Comment: Python can be backend. Like Ruby for example.

Comment: Yes, but how is backend python linked to the front end HTML?

Comment: Look up Flask, for example.

Comment: Is that what most people do?

Comment: Javascript (usually), HTML, CSS run in the browser (Node.JS is a JavaScript runtime environment, which can spawn a web server). Python, and other languages like Ruby and Golang, can be used to establish a "web server" that "serves" static assets (like HTML, CSS, JavaScript) to browsers (over HTTP/S).

Comment: Basically a "web server" is a software that renders the "html" for web browsers to consume. The "language" of the web server can include whatever dictates as needed and proscribed for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

So your code in browser is called front-end (FE). Sometimes it's all you need. However, sometimes you need to store some data on the server and/or retrieve it from there. That is where back-end (BE) comes into play.

BE is basically an app on some computer (maybe a server, maybe a Raspberry Pi, anything really) that listens to requests from the network. Let's say your code needs some data from the server. Your code on the front end makes an AJAX request to the network address of this server on some specific port. The BE, which may be written in Python, or any other language, receives the request and does something with it.

It can fetch data from the DB or anything really. Then it send a response to your FE back, sending some data, or confirmation that everything was done successfully, or an error if something went wrong.

Comment: Hey @elliott-weiss, please accept my answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Python is used for backend development. Backend is the part of your website that runs on your server, not browser. Backend is used for authentication and communicating with database and many more. There are some popular frameworks in python like django and flask.

Answer (score 0):

Google in front of you is called front end which is written in HTML, CSS, and JS and usually interpreted by browsers. In the end, HTML, CSS, and JS are all codes, thus, string (or binary).

Python is used to generate those strings, the codes, in back end.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN),

> **HTML — Structuring the web**
> HTML is the language that we use to structure the different parts of our content and define what their meaning or purpose is. This topic teaches HTML in detail.

> **CSS — Styling the web**
> CSS is the language that we can use to style and layout our web content, as well as adding behavior like animation. This topic provides comprehensive coverage of CSS.

> **JavaScript — Dynamic client-side scripting**
> JavaScript is the scripting language used to add dynamic functionality to web pages. This topic teaches all the essentials needed to become comfortable with writing and understanding JavaScript.

Below is where you will find how Python is linked to HTML, CSS, and JS.

> [**Server-side website programming**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side)
> Even if you are concentrating on client-side web development, it is still useful to know how servers and server-side code features work. This topic provides a general introduction to how the server-side works and detailed tutorials showing how to build up a server-side app using two popular frameworks: Django (Python) and Express (Node.js).

(Ref.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn)

Below, you can read more about

- what clients and servers are,
- how they are linked, and
- how and what the clients request to the servers and the servers respond to the clients

Some of the useful keywords are HTTP verbs (HTTP request methods), Uniform Resource Identifier (URI), and HTTP status code.

[An article about Back-End Web Architecture from Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/back-end-architecture)

*Note: As someone who just started programming, it could be really overwhelming to look for satisfying/precise answers across the web. You could also start from some reliable learning sources and search for the keywords to get a specific result. Happy learning!*

Answer (score 0):

The old way to to do this is with [cgi-bin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cgi-bin), which is an interface between the web-server and a program installed on the same machine.

When a user requests a *static* page, the web-server returns the contents a file, with some headers prefixed. cgi-bin allows for *dynamic* pages. Here the web-server runs a local program, passing it the URL and any headers from the client (web-browser). The program then generates the headers and body of the reply, and the web-server passes them back to the client. The program then exits.

The program can be written in any language. Perl was traditional, however Python or a compiled program is frequently used nowadays.

It was common to have cgi-bin at the start of URL to denote this to the server, but it isn't really needed - the server can be told that any specific (or all) URLs are to be fetched via cgi-bin.